Reusable ::testing::Values generator in gtest
I have a piece of software (c++) thats tested excessively with googletest.
There are a lot of INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P calls.
There is a particular value generator that I'd like to reuse, something that should not affect the test results but I found odd instances where it does. Think of it as seed for random, if that helps.
So there are numerous variations
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P( foo, foo, ::testing::Values(0,42,4711))
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P( bar, bar, ::testing::Values(0,42,4711))

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P( foobar, foobar, 
  ::testing::Combine(
    ::testing::Range(1,3),
    ::testing::Values(0,42,4711))

in any number of test files knocking around
I am looking for a way to turn ::testing::Values(0,42,4711) into a "name" that I can reuse (I am prepared for but not truly interested in lectures that it would be literal, lvalue, etc).
Once upon a time it would have been #define WITH_THE_ANNOYING_ONES ::testing::Values(0,42,4711) and that would turn my tests into
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P( foo, foo, WITH_THE_ANNOYING_ONES )
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P( bar, bar, WITH_THE_ANNOYING_ONES )

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P( foobar, foobar, 
  ::testing::Combine(
    ::testing::Range(1,3),
    WITH_THE_ANNOYING_ONES)

constexpr WITH_THE_ANNOYING_ONES = ::testing::Values(0,42,4711); didn't work for me
Is there any solution that doesn't use gtests ::internal stuff or macros?

You can do it in a lot of ways:

If possible, reuse instantiations
If you have a number of tests using the same data and, more importantly, the tests are related to each other, simply group them in one class fixture

class Foo: public ::testing::TestWithParam<int> {};
TEST_P(Foo, testsBar) {}
TEST_P(Foo, testsBaz) {}
// below line will instantiate both testsBar and testsBaz with the same data
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P( fooParameterisedTests, Foo, ::testing::Values(0,42,4711)); 


Store the parameter generator directly

const auto WITH_THE_ANNOYING_ONES = ::testing::Values(0,42,4711);

Your attempted failed due to missing auto and the fact that generator is not constexpr itself, so the variable cannot be constexpr as well. Plain old const is fine unless you need to place it in a header file to share between mutliple file - then it gets more involved.

Store values in any container and use ValuesIn generator

constexpr std::array WITH_THE_ANNOYING_ONES {0,42,4711};
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P( foo, foo, ::testing::ValuesIn(WITH_THE_ANNOYING_ONES));

When you choose container, normal container restrictions apply (e.g., std::vector cannot be constexpr, but std::array can).
